# How to get Groupinstance Object with scene.ray_cast?

Tags: python, scripting

I am using `scene.ray_cast` to get the underlying objects of the mouse.
That works perfectly fine for mesh objects. The problem comes with groupinstances (empty objects). They are refering to the objects of that group. Is there a way to get the empty object (group instance) with `scene.ray_cast`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to access the object that instances the duplicator.

In fact there could be many (a chain of parents in a nested hierarchy).